# for_each for a list of strings

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

I am creating a variable in terraform cloud and using that variable as an input to create a `random_pet` resource.

```
resource "tfe_variable" "names" {
  key          = "name_prefixes"
  value        = jsonencode(yamldecode(file("names_list.yaml")))
  workspace_id = "ws-id"
  hcl          = true
  category     = "terraform"  
}

resource "random_pet" "pet" {
  for_each = toset(tfe_variable.names.key)
  prefix = each.key
}
```

```
cat names_list.yaml

---
- "tfe"
- "tfc"
- "ansible"
- "puppet"
```

I am getting an error:

```
Error: Invalid function argument
on main.tf line 12, in resource "random_pet" "pet":
  for_each = toset(tfe_variable.names.key)
Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert string to set of any single type.
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only **one instance** of `tfe_variable.names`. Thus, there is nothing to iterate over. So you should just have:

```
resource "random_pet" "pet" {
  prefix = tfe_variable.names.key
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
resource "tfe_variable" "names" {

  key          = "name_prefixes"
  value        = jsonencode(yamldecode(file("names_list.yaml")))
  workspace_id = "ws-id"
  hcl          = true
  category     = "terraform"  
}

resource "random_pet" "pet" {
  for_each = toset(yamldecode(file("names_list.yaml")))
  prefix = each.value
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin, my goal is to have an iteration over every entry in names_list.yaml. Hence, I am using for_each. Since the file has four entries, I want four resources created.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I tried what you suggested. In that case, its creating four seperate "tfe_variable" resources. I want the variable to be like this:

name_prefixes = ["tfe","tfc","ansible","puppet"]
random_pet resource should iterate over each of these four values.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, that did the trick! In this solution, we dont even need the tfe_variable resource block to create random_pet resource, just the yaml file is enough.
Do you think is there a way we can make creation of random_pet resource dependent on tfe_variable and not straight on the yaml file?

Comment: @JaiminJoshi Just load it in a local variable first, and then reuse the variable.

Comment: I didnt understand @Marcin . . . can you please elaborate?